# Condition that checks placeholder content existence

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

How can I check placeholder content existence and make next trick? :

```
{% if placeholder 'Head_text' %} <--check here
   <div class="in">
      ...
         ...
             <h2 class="title">{% placeholder 'Head_text' %}</h2>
         ...
      ...
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

I want to know, does placeholder have some content before rendering some special HTML-structure for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a solution for this and I found a few alternatives instead of checking if the placeholder exists. Basically the idea is to use a different plugin instead that adds the extra html. There are a few packages you can install with pip. Now, **after trying them I just did it myself and it was much more easier than using the packages**.

1. [cmsplugin-text-wrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmsplugin-text-wrapper/0.6): It integrates to the existent django-cms default text plugin keeping the editor but adds a selector on top so you can select a `wrapper`. The `wrapper` contains the extra html you would like to add. It also has a nice CSS system to add classes. *On the downside, I didn't want to make the editors life more difficult with the extra template selector.*
2. [cmsplugin-text-ng](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmsplugin-text-ng): This basically adds a new plugin. When you add the plugin to your placeholder, it display a selector with the available templates (that contains your extra HTML). What I really like is that you can add extra fields that you can use in your customized HTML. For example, you could add a title so the plugin displays an extra textfield for it. *On the downside, the templates are store in the database through the admin!. That is an extra hit to the database and I really don't want to sacrifice it for something too simple.*
3. [Do your own plugin](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html) using the existent Text Model. Four very simple steps:

   3.1 Basically add this to your `cms_plugins.py`:

   ```
   from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
   from cms.plugins.text.models import Text
   from cms.plugins.text.cms_plugins import TextPlugin

   class WidgetPlugin(TextPlugin):
       model = Text
       name = _("Widget")
       render_template = "widget.html"

       def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
           context['instance'] = instance
           return context

   plugin_pool.register_plugin(WidgetPlugin)
   ```

   3.2 Create your `widget.html` template in your `templates` folder:

   ```
   <div class="in">
      ...
         ...
             {{ instance.body|safe }}
         ...
      ...
   </div>
   ```

   3.3 Place your placeholder wherever you want:

   ```
    {% placeholder 'Head_text' %}
   ```

   3.4 Make the user use the new plugin adding the `Head_text` configuration plugin in the `settings.py`:

   ```
   CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
       #...
       'Head_text': {
           'plugins': {'WidgetPlugin'}
       },
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, and when I researched it (this might have changed since) there is no built in way to do this, so you have to write your own template tag to load the placeholder into a variable.

Here are some discussions on the django-cms mailing list:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-cms/QeTlmxQnn3E
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-cms/2mWvEpTH0ns/discussion

Comment: The link you posted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-cms/WDUjIpSc23c/discussion) is [not working](https://gist.github.com/1818976). Where can I find the code for the template tag?